# Error Hadbling of subscription payment stripe

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, stripe-payments

I am working on stripe api gateway using node js library. bellow code for charge subscription but its always send the "**Purchase successful**" response even if I enter the wrong plan id. and showing the error "**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.**" So please anyone suggest me to how to handle such errors.

```
try {
    plans.forEach(function (planitem) {
        stripe.subscriptions.create({
                customer: custId,
                // default_tax_rates:planitem.tax_rates,
                items: [{
                    plan: 'aasasasaaa'
                }]
            }).then(subscriptions => {
                console.log(subscriptions);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                next(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                    status: 0,
                    message: "Purchase Failed"
                });
            });
    });
    res.status(200).json({
        status: 1,
        message: "Purchase successful"
    });
} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({
        status: 0,
        message: "Purchase Failed"
    });
}
```

Thanks